# input blur not works properly on ipad

Tags: html, ios, google-chrome, ipad, safari

I have the following piece of html:

```
<input type="text" />
<h1>test</h1>
```

If I focus the input and touch outside in specific areas, the input sometimes does not lose the focus (blur event).

The problem occurs both in Chrome and Safari on iPad.